# Redis multi - is it thread safe?

Tags: redis

Does Redis guarantee that no other command will be processed in the middle of multi command?

For example - All of the following commands are sent at the same time from different machines:

```
multi-command1:
1. get x
2. set y

other commands sent at the same time separately:
3. set z
```

does the outcome in redis queue will always be one of the following:

```
1. get x
2. set y
3. set z
```

or:

```
1. set z
2. get x
3. set y
```

---

Or it can be:

```
1. get x
2. set z
3. set y
```

which is not thread safe at all (in case the developer is writing the multi-command in such a way that he assumes no one can process something in the middle of the multi-command execution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as you've described in the 1st option, the commands within the MULTI/EXEC block would be run atomically (i.e. thread-safe).